# Преобразовать ═юьхэъырЄєЁр в Номенклатура в С#

Tags: c#, кодировка, dbf

Задача при чтении файла DBF III с записанной в поле файла заголовка CodePage 201, текст выглядит абракадаброй.
В частности слово Номенклатура как `═юьхэъырЄєЁр`

Обычный подход не работает, так как дает то же самое на выходе `═юьхэъырЄєЁр`

```
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");
var testStr = "═юьхэъырЄєЁр";

var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(win1251, utf8,  testStr.ToByteArray(win1251)));
```

Есть варианты? Всем спасибо!

Тут преобразуется https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru в Номенклатура

Comment: У DBF dBASE III поле CodePage (по смещению 0x1D) не используется, его бессмысленно проверять. Оно появилось только в dBASE IV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251").GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866").GetBytes("═юьхэъырЄєЁр"));
```